# Does MVC normally have a separate Controller for every View?

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm just browsing MVC examples so far, and I think I'm getting a handle on it. For my project - an embedded system on ARM9, no Windows/ASP at all - we are considering doing all the UI as MVC. Does MVC also require a strict Tree of all UI Views (one root?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one controller may have different views for different actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the controller into a front controller and several actions.
As reference see [The MVC Pattern](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_0/02-Exploring-Symfony-s-Code) as implemented into Symfony framework.

Answer (score 0):

If your views are parts of a full page you might also use the same view from different controllers. Ie header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

A controller can have many views and partial views. If you take a look at some simple ASP .NET MVC tutorials: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 you'll learn how this can be done easily.